# What would be the best strategy to match color dominants between two pictures?

Tags: opencv

I need to match the color dominant between two different pictures, to make them as similar as possible.

For example,I would like to match the grayscale picture of the child below, to the sepia picture of the soldier and compensate for contrast and lighning.

So far, I am thinking to convert the pictures to YCrCb and match the contrast on the histogram of the Y channel and the color in the other channels.

I will have to do the same also between color pictures.

Any suggestions?

[image: Grayscale image of a child]

[image: Color scan of a B&W image]

Comment: I find your question very hard to understand. What do you mean by *"I want to transform a greyscale image into a black and white image with the right colour"*? Surely neither greyscale nor black and white images have any colour? Can you maybe add some pictures to illustrate?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have reworded my question trying to clarify the problem.

Comment: I had success with histogram matchng. I started from the code in this tutorial, which basically is an automated version of the process well described below http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/01/28/recoloring-via-histogram-matching-with-opencv-w-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some ideas that should be of use - they kind of start in Photoshop and wander through Perl, ImageMagick and OpenCV. I am a big fan of the warm and beautiful tonalities achieved by photographers such as [David Fokos](http://davidfokos.net) and [Michael Kenna](http://www.michaelkenna.net) and I worked out, many years back, how to replicate their toning.

First, load your image up in Photoshop, convert to black and white mode, and then back to RGB mode, add a Curves adjustment layer and a new layer with the original colour image. Your Layers window will look like this:

[image]

Now turn off all layers except the grey background, and use the Color Dropper to find and mark:

- a quarter-tone pixel (i.e. value around 64 in the Info window)
- a mid-tone pixel (i.e. around 128 in the Info window)
- a three quarter-tone pixel (i.e. around 192 in the Info window)

[image]

Now turn the other layers back on and find what those three tones map to in RGB:

[image]

Now go in the Curves layer and adjust the Red, Green and Blue curves to match those values:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And if you then switch back to RGB, you can see all three curves on one diagram:

[image]

You now just need to save that Curve as a file with `ACV` extension and you can apply it to other images:

[image]

I got a bit bored doing that, so I wrote a Perl script that does exactly the same. You pass it a toned image as a filename, it finds the quarter, mid and three-quarter tones and then creates an Adobe Photoshop Curves file - an ACV file for you which you can then batch apply to other photos.

Here's the Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;
use Data::Dumper;

my $Debug=1;    # 1=print debug messages, 0=don't
my $NPOINTS=5;  # Number of points in curve we create

# Read in image in first parameter
my $imagename=$ARGV[0];
my $orig=Image::Magick::->new;
my $x = $orig->Read($imagename);
  warn "$x" if "$x";

my $width =$orig->Get('columns');
my $height=$orig->Get('rows');
my $depth=$orig->Get('depth');
print "DEBUG: ",$width,"x",$height,", depth: ",$depth,"\n" if $Debug;

# Access pixel cache
my @RGBpixels  = $orig->GetPixels(map=>'RGB',height=>$height,width=>$width,normalize=>1);

my ($i,$j,$p);
my (@greypoint,@Rpoint,@Gpoint,@Bpoint);
for($p=0;$p<$NPOINTS;$p++){
   my $greylevelsought=int(($p+1)*256/($NPOINTS+1));
   my $nearestgrey=1000;
   for(my $t=0;$t<$height*$width;$t++){
         my $R = int(255*$RGBpixels[(3*$t)+0]);
         my $G = int(255*$RGBpixels[(3*$t)+1]);
         my $B = int(255*$RGBpixels[(3*$t)+2]);
         my $this=int(0.21*$R + 0.72*$G +0.07*$B);
         printf "Point: %d, Greysought: %d, this pixel: %d\n",$p,$greylevelsought,$this if $Debug>1;
         if(abs($this-$greylevelsought)<abs($nearestgrey-$greylevelsought)){
            $nearestgrey=$this;
            $greypoint[$p]=$nearestgrey;
            $Rpoint[$p]=$R;
            $Gpoint[$p]=$G;
            $Bpoint[$p]=$B;
         }
   }
   printf "DEBUG: Point#: %d, sought grey: %d, nearest grey: %d\n",$p,$greylevelsought,$nearestgrey if $Debug;
}

# Work out name of the curve file = image basename + acv
my $curvefile=substr($imagename,0,rindex($imagename,'.')) . ".acv";
open(my $out,'>:raw',$curvefile) or die "Unable to open: $!";
print $out pack("s>",4); # Version=4
print $out pack("s>",4); # Number of curves in file = Master NULL curve + R + G + B

print $out pack("s>",2);            # Master NULL curve with 2 points for all channels
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );   # 0 out, 0 in
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);   # 255 out, 255 in

print $out pack("s>",2+$NPOINTS);       # Red curve
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );   # 0 out, 0 in
for($p=0;$p<$NPOINTS;$p++){
   print $out pack("s>",$Rpoint[$p]),pack("s>",$greypoint[$p]);
}
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);   # 255 out, 255 in

print $out pack("s>",2+$NPOINTS);       # Green curve
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );   # 0 out, 0 in
for($p=0;$p<$NPOINTS;$p++){
   print $out pack("s>",$Gpoint[$p]),pack("s>",$greypoint[$p]);
}
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);   # 255 out, 255 in

print $out pack("s>",2+$NPOINTS);       # Blue curve
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );    # 0 out, 0 in
for($p=0;$p<$NPOINTS;$p++){
   print $out pack("s>",$Bpoint[$p]),pack("s>",$greypoint[$p]);
}
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);    # 255 out, 255 in

close($out);
```

If you want to do this in OpenCV, you could translate the first 70% of the script to OpenCV pretty simply - it is just 2 loops. Then you would have the quarter, mid and three-quarter tone points. You could use a curve-fitting program such as `gnuplot` (I have no idea of your skillset) to fit a curve to the points and then generate a lookup table for each of the 256 values 0-255, and apply that to your other images using `cv::LUT()` to replicate or clone the tone.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to do my processing in real time, since one of the images it a snapshot taken on the fly. Still, your discussion is very useful and it might spark the right code.
Oh, by the way, I think it might work for color too, what do you think?
I will have to match pictures taken on the fly with vintage color images.

Comment: Presumably your vintage images are old ;-) so you must already have them, so you could potentially pre-generate the curves ahead of time before you do your real-time acquisition and just apply them. I haven't looked at it in any detail, but maybe you could add your vintage curves into the `Magic Lantern` firmware that runs on some Canon cameras.