# Wratten photography filter in python / numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, photoshop

I am writing an application wherein I want to be able to apply photography filters to an image, similar to photoshop's Adjustments->Photo Filter tool.

I think I have a vague idea of the process, but if anybody could fill in any of the details, here, that would be great!

1) First off, I think I need to get a mapping of wratten filter numbers to spectrum curves (I couldn't find any.  The best I found was a [pdf image of a table](http://www.karmalimbo.com/aro/pics/filters/transmision%20of%20wratten%20filters.pdf), which would really suck to enter manually.)

2) Then I need to convert each pixel from rgb to color spectrum. (Is that equivalent to HSV?)

3) Map each pixel based on interpolating its point on the curve from step 1.  (Or is it 1.0-that since photo filters are based on transmission?)

4) Convert the result back into rgb.

Comment: One day when I was bored, I wrote some code to extract the parameters needed to mimic the toning effect in any given, toned image and make a Photoshop `.ACV` (Adobe Curves File) file that I could apply to other images. Do you have any Wratten-filtered images available? The process is described here - I could probably do it in Python now if it works for Wratten filters... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48498270/2836621

Comment: Do you have a set of images taken with and without the filter? You can learn the parameters needed. If the paired images contained a wide variety of colors it would help.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see that it is an artificial filter. If you can take five images, map them through filter, and upload the original and filtered images somewhere, I'd like to work on this. One approach is to learn a nonlinear mapping `f(p) = q` between input and output pixels

Comment: Going by the comments it seems I should be more specific. There isn't just one particular filter that I want to mimick, but rather I want an application I'm writing to be able to apply any given one.

I've changed the question to better reflect this.

Comment: Did you find any thing to replicate the photo filter algorithm? I'm also interested.