# How to infer PIL enhancement factors and colorization color based on input and output image?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have a png **input** image.

[image: Input image]

Consider that someone have done some manipulation in this input image using only the following libraries:

- First someone used **ImageOps.colorize** to applied a certain **color** to the image ("#ffd03a" in the example bellow)
- Next someone used **ImageEnhance** to change Contrast and Brightness by certain **factors** (1.3 and 1.5 in the example below)

```
    color = "#ffd03a"
    input = Image.open("input.png")
    
    r,g,b,a = input.split()    
    gray = ImageOps.grayscale(input)
    out = ImageOps.colorize(gray, (0, 0, 0, 0), color) 
    out.putalpha(a)
    
    ce = ImageEnhance.Contrast(out)
    out = ce.enhance(1.3)
    
    be = ImageEnhance.Brightness(out)
    out = be.enhance(1.1)
```

Now lets consider I do not know what color and factors were used. I want to create a code to brute force discover what color and factor were used to obtain certain output image. The output image was resized and converted back and forth:

[image: Output image]

I've thought about iterating over all colors, and over a predefined array of values for factors. How can I compare my calculated image with the original output image to obtain the closest guess of **color** and **factors**?

Comment: Is it the case that you want to know the numbers this mysterious other person used, or is it sufficient to be able to achieve the same effect but possibly by other means?

Comment: @MarkSetchell by other means, is fine. As long as reproducible because i have to apply the discovered process to a bunch of other pictures

Comment: I did something ages ago... have a read here and see if that is of interest https://stackoverflow.com/a/48498270/2836621